# Как найти изображение (координаты) объекта в Google Street View

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Например у меня есть фото объекта в городе N, я хочу найти расположение этого объекта в сервисе Google Street View, не просматривая огромное количество улиц данного города.

Пример: 
1) У нас фото какого то памятника города N. Мы можем обходить все улицы через Google Street View в поисках, но как это сделать быстро?
Чтобы в итоге найти координаты этого места?

Comment: Например как найти где это находится ? 
![изображение](https://4.404content.com/1/A0/D7/910119070985619218/fullsize.jpg).
При условии что поиск по картинке Google ничего нам не дал, но мы точно уверены что этот памятник стоит на одной из главных улиц некоего города или поселка. 

Возможно здесь необходимо применять нейронные сети для поиска объекта, на случай если данная функция еще не реализована Google и соответственно отсутствует в API (на мой взгляд). 
А что думаете Вы?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте **[Google Images](https://images.google.com/)** и ведите свой запрос в поле поиска и нажмите кнопку "Поиск изображений". Для примера я ввожу предложенный вами линк картинки. Выдача: не найдено ни одной картинки по этому линку. Но также есть опция **Поиск по картинке**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Щелкаем по ней и **[поисковая выдача](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisawmxKVibUxocqQacUCRVQPVvL0Sn6OAKkSOovKobf-14sTjgi55XS0MGiWB5sCtiwI5OMZKF0VxiFfagnbSEtugj7qiXmhxK0lV5nJrbc_1_1FQhyv3CXT_1sZaoEag9OkHlhqLxCLP2rbwVEJtFnxm5VjlpnOA4nO9VuG0_1ohKUxTp4NLsahvj3LdwFaZxCk_1FI1aTM9KQiow9aQon0ctUXGSlrk0wHA6wv6ZvWDMfFvOAPLyS3GiQCNwt60jFgaxsCXkdQAJ2WLZJ4rJZEsUleWBvCApBwEH5LTkkDfKks6rbcEDaXaRS_1iTwQFlMSD7loFbWUzkzkmLHd3EkHVnYnkvzLlQ&hl=ru&biw=1280&bih=670&site=search&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUxKvkyODVAhViApoKHe-FBxMQ9Q8IIigA)** сообщает, что "***Скорее всего, на картинке  Легенда о пермском медведе***". Обратите внимание, что эта фраза выдана как ссылка. Далее выдан список "Похожие изображения", также как ссылка. Далее выдан список "Страницы с подходящими изображениями". На первом месте в этом списке расположена статья Википедии "*[Легенда о пермском медведе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5)*" Если вы откроете эту статью, то справа от заголовка статьи вы увидите знак карты, цифры (координаты) и латинские буквы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы установите курсор на этих буквах, то там появится всплывающая подсказка. Надеюсь, что помог вам.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю решение вы сможете увидеть в [cтатье](https://awik.io/extract-gps-location-exif-data-photos-using-javascript/) там же есть [рабочий пример](https://awik.io/demo/exif/)

Это не совсем ответ на вопрос но может пригодится в решении задачи если геоданные есть в файле фотографии.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#file-input").on("change", function(e) {
      EXIF.getData(e.target.files[0], function() {
          var result = EXIF.pretty(this);   //EXIF.getTag(this,'GPSLatitude')
          $("#span").text(result);
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exif-js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="file-input" />
  <span id="span">Here</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Попробуйте EXIF.getTag(this,'GPSLatitude'), Вы получите 3 пары, которые разделены запятыми (,). вы можете преобразовать их в строку и разбить на массив, продолжая оставшиеся шаги.